# SkipPolicy do Spring Batch, para que serve?

Tags: java, spring

Gostaria de saber para que serve o **SkipPolicy** que é setado no StepBuilderFactory.

Se possível gostaria de alguma documentação explicando.

Comment: Poderia dar algum exemplo do contexto em que você está usando?

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com a [documentação](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/step/skip/SkipPolicy.html), uma classe que implementa a interface `SkipPolicy` deve determinar um critério para quando um processamento (`Step`) deve ser executado, ou não. A interface possui o método `boolean shouldSkip(java.lang.Throwable t, int skipCount) throws SkipLimitExceededException` que deve retornar `true` caso o `Step` deve continuar normalmente se a `Throwable t` for lançada durante a execução do passo, ou `false` caso contrário. Já o parâmetro `skipCount` corresponde ao número de vezes que o passo foi pulado dada a execução atual.